# why a href tag uses only # as dummy link why not * or any other special character?

Tags: html, http, url

Why does a href tag use '#' specifically as a dummy link, in regards to using something like a '*' or other kind of special character? Does alternatives to this exist, or is one forced to use '#'? Furthermore, what is '#' that allows HTML to see it as a dummy link?

Comment: The `#` is a fragment in HTML. That's not dummy, but it is a segment identifier, identified by `name="fragmant"` or `id="fragment"`.

Comment: we can just left it as null you know ,why to specify with # is thier any particular future use in php ,.net or any other backend use

Comment: If you leave it like `""`, it links back to the same page. Did you try it out?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar: That still causes a page load, though.

Comment: @BoltClock Yep, that's what I meant. It causes a page reload right?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar: Indeed it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the other characters you listed don't have any special meaning and are instead treated as part of the URL. # on the other hand represents a fragment identifier, and an empty fragment identifier represents nothing. A hyperlink to an empty fragment identifier does not cause a navigation — instead, it simply kicks the user back to the top of the page they're on.

The other characters don't represent "wrong" URLs — they just represent *different* URLs, which means they will be navigated to, which is not what you want in a dummy link that is not supposed to navigate anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Because '#' is used to search for an id in the current page, so if the symbol is used alone, clicking on the link will make you stay where you are.

Comment: we can just leave it " " (null) right?

Comment: Of course. Both lead to the same result.

Comment: @AlixEisenhardt Are you sure? Try giving `<a href="">` vs. `<a href="#">` and tell me what's the difference you see.

Comment: It just add '#' at the end of the url. If you have an example where it makes a problem, I'm interested.

Comment: @AlixEisenhardt Here you go. Demos will help you to understand better. http://output.jsbin.com/cohobojace

Comment: I had never seen it that way. I do not use forms often and when I do, I do not have empty links. Thanks !

Comment: @AlixEisenhardt It's not about forms mate. I am saying that the empty links initiate a new page request and refresh the old page. `#` just takes to the top of the page.